# React-Bootstrap-Typeahead trouble rendering data returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch

In their example in the docs it shows the following:

```
<AsyncTypeahead
  onSearch={query => (
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${query}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({options: json.items}));
  )}
  options={this.state.options}
/>
```

I have instead a function that sits in the container which, via a Redux "action" returns a list of suburbs.

I am having firstly trouble structuring the "fetch" command so that the return suburbs are set as an "options" object.

Secondly, I am also having trouble setting up the AsyncTypeahead component.

Here is my fetch statement - the APi returns results but I have a syntax error on options "unused label".

```
   const task = fetch('/api/SelectData/QuerySuburbs' + queryString, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
  })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response =>  {options: response}))
      console.log('response ', response)
```

Here is my function that is supposed to return options... I suspect it doesnt, at least not in the format that the AsyncTypeahead requires..

```
  handleSuburbSearch = (query) => {
    const {selectData} = this.props
    const companyStateId = selectData.companyStateId

    if (!query) {
      return;
    }
    const queryString = {
      query: query,
      companyStateId: companyStateId,
    }
    const suburbs = getSuburbs(queryString)
    return suburbs
  };
```

And here is the way my AsyncTypeahead is structured:

```
<AsyncTypeahead
  name={name}
  onSearch= {query => (handleSuburbSearch(query))}
  renderMenuItemChildren={(options) => renderMenuItemChildren(options)}
  placeholder="Select Suburb"
/>
```

so the above actually kicks off a search - goes off and we get data from the API and then it gets lost.

I am having trouble with the Fetch structure so as to return an "options" object and, I believe, with the way I have the basic AsyncTypeahead syntax structured..

How should I structure the Fetch so it will return options?

How do I structure the AsyncTypeahead so it displays retrieved results?

**REFERENCES**

I have been using [this](http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#asynchronous-searching) example from the React-Bootstrap-Typeahead:

```
 const AsyncExample = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      allowNew: false,
      multiple: false,
      options: [],
    };
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AsyncTypeahead
          {...this.state}
          labelKey="login"
          onSearch={this._handleSearch}
          placeholder="Search for a Github user..."
          renderMenuItemChildren={this._renderMenuItemChildren}
        />
        {this._renderCheckboxes()}
      </div>
    );
  },

  _renderCheckboxes() {
    const checkboxes = [
      {label: 'Multi-Select', name: 'multiple'},
      {label: 'Allow custom selections', name: 'allowNew'},
    ];

    return checkboxes.map(({label, name}) => (
      <Checkbox
        checked={this.state[name]}
        key={name}
        name={name}
        onChange={this._handleChange}>
        {label}
      </Checkbox>
    ));
  },

  _renderMenuItemChildren(option, props, index) {
    return (
      <div key={option.id}>
        <img
          src={option.avatar_url}
          style={{
            height: '24px',
            marginRight: '10px',
            width: '24px',
          }}
        />
        <span>{option.login}</span>
      </div>
    );
  },

  _handleChange(e) {
    const {checked, name} = e.target;
    this.setState({[name]: checked});
  },

  _handleSearch(query) {
    if (!query) {
      return;
    }

    fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${query}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({options: json.items}));
  },
});
```

As well as [This](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/API.md#asynctypeahead) example from the docs area.

```
<AsyncTypeahead
  onSearch={query => (
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${query}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({options: json.items}));
  )}
  options={this.state.options}
/>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever pass the fetched data back into the typeahead. Notice that in the docs/examples, `this.state.options` is passed to the component, with `options` being set in the `fetch` call.